# defaultValue in Touch UI dialogs - AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

For classic UI there is a option to set `defaultValue` for fields, this is shown to user when user first time opens the dialog after dragging the component. If user clears the value in dialog and saves, on editing the dialog, value of field is not shown again.

For touch UI dialog, couldn't find the equivalent of `defaultValue`. There are following options

1. `emptyText` - But this is kind of placeholder text. If user wants to save form without entering value, this is not useful.
2. `value` - This shows the value when first time component is opened for authoring. But if user clears the value and saves. From the JCR structure the value is removed. But if user opens the dialog for editing, the value is again shown in the field, while this should be empty.

If there a equivalent of `defaultValue` in touch UI dialog or any other way of handling this (may be listeners or something else)

Comment: In TouchUI only `numberfield` provides the attribute `defaultValue` you can look at Granite Documentation for different available fields at  https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield/index.html

Comment: What should happen if the user does not save the dialog at all? Should the value be stored in JCR anyway or should the JCR property be empty?

Comment: As per the `defaultValue` behavior, the value in JCR is empty unless saved through dialog. I was looking for similar alternate for Touch UI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `defaultValue` or `value`, I feel like you should be using `cq:template` node. You can achieve this by adding `nt:unstructured` type of node with `cq:template` name under the component. Like this:

*_cq_template/.content.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sampleProperty="Default value of sampe property">
```

Comment: Checked `cq:template`, as soon as we drag component, the property value is saved in content JCR structure. This kind of works, though not exactly similar to `defaultValue`. We had checks based on property value to show author "Configure this component" on first time drag kind of text, so the check needs to be applied in different manner or may be default value needs to be different, against which we can apply check.

Comment: This is SO obscure. I wasted half of the day trying to figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning to set a `select` field in the `design dialog` with `dropdown` for default values and then work with it in the cq-dialog with `value="${cqDesign.type}"`

Answer (score 0):

Since `numberfield` is also mentioned in this discussion. I have got `value` working instead of `defaultValue` in granite UI.

```
<numberOfResults
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/numberfield"
    fieldLabel="Number Of Results"
    required="{Boolean}true"
    value="10"
    name="./numberOfResults"/>
```

**Limitation** (snippet from mentioned thread):

The `value` property values only persist if `jcr:created` and `jcr:lastModified` date is same for a component node in content. That means once component is authored, the dialog values will be fetched from save properties. Make this field mandatory if you wish to keep a value either default or authored value. That solves the problem of always populating it.

**Thread**
Refer https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/defaultvalue-property-removed-in-coral-numberfield-in-aem-6-4/qaq-p/292673 for more details.