# Default values for AEM dialog properties (Sightly)

Tags: aem, sightly

I need to set a default dialog value in AEM component.
For example - I have dialog with node - namelabel
and I am fetching this in my html as

```
${properties.namelabel}
```

Now I want to set the default value to this node property, ie when I am editing a dialog there is always a value set as

```
namelabel : Name
```

where in author can change this anytime he wants.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: classic or touch ?

Comment: more extensively if touch - how do you create your dialog - via dialog or _cq_dialog ?

Comment: @ub1k I am trying this in touch ui -cq-dialog. I am not facing any error here, I am just looking for an approach for how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short - you could use property `value` which is presented as the default value in touch dialog.

your question is though a sort of duplicate of what's been said here: [defaultValue in Touch UI dialogs - AEM/CQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640339/defaultvalue-in-touch-ui-dialogs-aem-cq)

Comment: this is wrong, if the value is updated with new string, then you still see default value, not updated one.