# Set default value in dialog box in AEM

Tags: aem

Can anyone help me in addressing query. I want to set a default value for a property in dialog box. Can anyone help me how to set default value for a property in dialog box which can be chnaged later.

Comment: what is the xtype of you are looking for? have a look at [defaultvalue-in-touch-ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640339/defaultvalue-in-touch-ui-dialogs-aem-cq)

Comment: xtype is selection.

Comment: cq:template node is the way to go

Comment: @shashibala updated my answer with selection xtype for classic UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Example taking `textfield` xtype

**Classic UI**
Have a look at the document of [widgets API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=Array) you can have always set them by using `defaultValue` property for the dialog fields with your respective xtypes that you wanted.

**Touch UI**
Touch UI the same can be set by using `value` property when you are using `sling:resourceType` pointing to `granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield`

> Example for the `Selection` xtype

**Classic UI:**

1. Create a component `simpleselection` save
2. Create a dialog under the component by  right click `Create Dialog` option
3. have your dialog as shown below. the `defaultValue` on the `xtype`  `selection` should be able to do the magic for your requirement.
   [image: dialogstructure]
   [image: jsondialog]

[image: page dialog]

**For Touch UI** you can find [article](http://adobeaemclub.com/touch-ui-dynamic-selection-of-multiple-drop-downs-in-aem-6-1/), [forum](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__6e0i-_i_am_tryingtoset.html)

Comment: Thanks.I have one more query.I have a checkbox in dialog box. Based on if it is checked or not.I  want to hide image.Can you please tell how to do this

Comment: This seems to be an unrelated query. Please consider raising a separated question.

Comment: @shashibala have a look at my blog [simple-dam-image-retrieval-example](https://aemvardhan.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/simple-dam-image-retrieval-example/) for your image example. ~Hope it helps

Comment: Can we pre-populate multifield values also, in touch ui ?